# How can I make a question of a state?

Tags: stative-verbs

For action, we say, ‘what are you doing’? But when I wonder about a state or condition of someone, how should I express?

Comment: *How are you doing?* works.

Answer (score 1):

A state would normally be answered with an adjective, eg "I am happy". So the natural question is "How are you?" or "How are you doing?"

If you want a specific question, you have lots of options.  To ask about age there is "How old are you?" To ask about the location of home "Where do you live" and so on.